# Are you able to recreate this site on local machine?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Seems obvious to recreate a site -- just copy the files over and it should work. But it doesn't for me. I've tried copying down all the scripts, images, and .html files but it doesn't seem to be displaying anything. All the paths are right btw, and still all black.

[This](http://iacopoapps.appspot.com/hopalongwebgl/) is the website.

Advice?

Comment: Open up your javascript console, it might give you a huge hint.

Comment: Yes I've tried that - there aren't any missing files / errors.

Comment: Odd, is Three.js running? It should print out in the console it has been launched, if not try using a local web server as suggested below (or even a remote one)

Comment: I'm going to try and run it using a local web server, and I'll keep you posted!

Answer (score 0):

try to run it for local web server like apache 
if you are using windows try use wamp server

Please Checkout this link for how to run three.js on local machine

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally